# Navigation bar pushes content down on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

I am having an issue with my navigation bar on my website, particularly the `<a>` elements and their hover states. I am using `box-sizing: border-box` for my entire website, and have the borders of the `<a>` elements animate in when they are hovered. However, the problem is that when they are hovered, they somehow push the main content down (the height increases about 0.33 pixels more than it should). The height of the `<a>` element is set at 44 pixels, but when hovered, it somehow increases 0.33 px over this limit and pushes the content down. This is somewhat difficult to explain, so I’ve created a short video exactly detailing my problem, please view it here: https://youtu.be/iEyVXqoQV74

Here is a link to my live website: http:// arkelectronics.ca/
Please note: this link will not display the problem in the future once I have fixed it.

You can view all the files for my website (before the fix) on the “pre_fix_stackoverflow” branch on GitHub here: https://github.com/Twinbird24/ark_electronics/tree/pre_fix_stackoverflow

The HTML for my nav bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The associated CSS for my nav bar:

```
nav li a {
    height: 44px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ededed; /* will be animated-in on hover */
    border-top: 0px solid orange; /* will be animated-in on hover */
    transition: border 200ms; /* the transition is applies to the border only, at a speed of 200ms */
    display: table-cell; /* this, as well as the vertical-align, ensures text is vertically centered every time inside the nav buttons*/
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* when nav button is hovered over */
nav li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 13px solid #ededed;
    border-top: 13px solid orange;
}

/* when the mouse is held down on nav button */
nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ededed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this like this :

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* removes the bullet-point that's common with ul elements */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've add `overflow: hidden;` property on it because there is a bug on IE10.

Then like this :

```
nav li a {
    height: 45px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ededed; /* will be animated-in on hover */
    border-top: 0px solid orange; /* will be animated-in on hover */
    transition: border 200ms; /* the transition is applies to the border only, at a speed of 200ms */
    display: table-cell; /* this, as well as the vertical-align, ensures text is vertically centered every time inside the nav buttons*/
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I changed the `height` property. Works good on IE10 now, hope it's good for you.

Comment: Changing the height fixed it, thanks! May I ask what exactly `overflow: hidden;` fixes? I did not notice anything different when I added this property (just curious).

Comment: I had a bug on IE10 where the content below was beside the navbar menu. It happens when you have float elements inside such as <li> :)

Answer (score 0):

on line 81 of your css change height to 51 px
                           nav li a {
                        background-color: transparent;
                        border-bottom: 0 solid #ededed;
                        border-top: 0 solid orange;
                        color: white;
                        display: table-cell;
                        height: 51px;
                        padding: 0 8px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        transition: border 200ms ease 0s;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }

Comment: And the site is not responsive so stop right now and worry about that first-